# Query Time Out Exception in start method of Batch

Tags: apex, batch, query

I recently came across the above issue where the Batch uses a query which causes the it to fail due to the
**Query timeout exception**.

I'm unable to create the scenario again as I found in the docs that salesforce can decide to run the query longer depending on the resources available.

I would like to know what kind of exception is this i.e., LIMIT/QUERY so that I can use some try catch to processed accordingly.

Is there any work around to know that the batch has failed without monitoring the apex jobs to find the same.

All suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Batches are stated to support up to 50000000 records. I have never come across a query timeout caused by a query locator returned by `start`. Do you know how many records the batch might have been processing?

Comment: I came across this problem some months ago and I started by checking how many records where being retrieved, as Phill mentioned, and then the query analyzer to see if indexes where being used in that environment. The end result was changes on the query like removing `not null`, breaking the batch in chunks, adding custom indexes, and addition of a skinny table.

Comment: 'Query timeout exception' just like any other System/Governor Limit exception can't be caught. The issue with the querylocator timing out, can be caused due to the data volume being queried, or if the query is not optimized. You can check the query plan for the SOQL that's timing out. And check if you can make the query more selective. check SOQL optimizations here - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000336230&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I've checked the query and it was not optimized. I would like to know if there is any approach to monitor daily scheduled batches which might fail because of any similar limit exception.